# Hibernate Example for Id column

Tags: hibernate

When I use hibernate Example API the Id column gets simply ignored, that is very annoying.

I have a Table Temp(Id, Descr) and respective entity.

And I want to do this:

```
Temp exampleObject;
exampleObject.setId(6);
exampleObject.setDescr("six");

DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(exampleObject.getClass()).add(example);
....
```

and the resulting sql looks like this

```
select this_.ID as ID0_0_, this_.DESCR as DESCR0_0_ 
from test.temp this_ where (lower(this_.DESCR)=?)
```

Where is this_.ID = 6?

Another strange behavior is when creating example only with Id:

```
Temp exampleObject;
exampleObject.setId(6);

DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(exampleObject.getClass()).add(example);
....
```

and resulting sql is:

```
select this_.ID as ID0_0_, this_.DESCR as DESCR0_0_ 
from test.temp this_ where (1=1)
```

Why my Id restriction is being ignored?

Here is my Hibernate mapping file:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "temp", catalog = "test")
public class Temp implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9123374914153833823L;

    private int id;
    private String descr;

    public Temp() {
    }

    public Temp(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Temp(int id, String descr) {
        this.id = id;
        this.descr = descr;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "DESCR", length = 45)
    public String getDescr() {
        return this.descr;
    }

    public void setDescr(String descr) {
        this.descr = descr;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Temp [id=" + id + ", descr=" + descr + "]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about this problem for a wile, I come up with explanation! There is no reason to someone to add Primary Key into find by Example search, as there is only one record with this Id and its simpler to just use get() or load(). That's why Id column is ignored in [Hibernate Example API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Example.html).

Comment: I've a login validation in which i need to check primerykey username and password column.

Answer (score 0):

I assume ID is your Primary Key. if so how did you mapped your ID column in the HBM file. 
if you mapped your ID to some kind of Foriegn Key or Auto Generated number or Sequence then you can't set your application driven numbers to define the Primary Key.

Hibernate Does it for you and you don;t have to explictly say Temp.setId(9). it will be obsolete.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I dont think this is an issue. I added hibernate mapping file to the question, so you can see that there are no Sequences or Foreign Keys in it.

Answer (score 0):

@Column is redundant when you use @Id, and you need to add ASSIGNED  stratergy to assign id from the application

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.ASSIGNED)
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```